# dropLast method throws fatal error can not decrement startIndex

Tags: string, swift, fatal-error

In some code I wrote, I have an array

> var numbas = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

In an effort to sift out non-numbers, I wrote the following code:

```
override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification)
 {
    for x in numbas{

        if entryText.stringValue.rangeOfString(x) == nil{

            if currentDegRadorFoo != "foo" {

                println("hi")

                entryText.stringValue = dropLast(entryText.stringValue)
            }
        }

    }
```

The idea is that if a character is not present within the numba array, then it should be deleted immediately. However, the code crashes every time it gets to 
`entryText.stringValue = dropLast(entryText.stringValue).`

When I get rid of just the method dropLast, and am left with `entryText.stringValue =(entryText.stringValue)`,

It runs fine, just without deleting the string. What is it about `dropLast` then, that is making the program crash? Previously, I had used an array of all the letters ["a",..."z"] and had said

> if entryText.stringValue.rangeOfString(x) != nil

this worked fine, even with dropLast. Is this a swift bug, or is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Maybe due to an empty string?

Comment: Wouldn't you know. I think this is because an empty string "" is also not included in the list in the list of numbers. Thanks!